# Copy files to a new folder if the file name matches value from a specific field in a feature class

Tags: arcpy, python

I have this folder with bunch of .jp2 files, and from this folder I need to copy only the files that their name matches the value name from a specific field in a feature class. Right now I can print the values name, but kind of stuck on the copy function. I don't get an error when running the script, but nothing gets copied.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os, shutil, arcpy

workdir = os.path.join(r'G:\County','JPEG2000','1Foot')
dst = os.path.join(r'T:\gis','Images2017','jp2','1foot')

allFiles = os.listdir(workdir)

path = r"T:\gis\airphoto\Images\Images2017_Mosaic.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = path

fc = r"T:\gis\airphoto\Images2017\Images2017_Mosaic.gdb\Extent_1ft"

rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc)

fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc,'FILENAME')

for row in rows:
   for field in fields:
      fieldName = field.name
      value = row.getValue(fieldName)
      print (field.name+": "+ str(value))

for aFile in allFiles:
   if aFile == str(value):
      shutil.copyfile(workdir,dst)
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your question so the indentation will not cause an error

Comment: What results do you get from printing aFile and str(value)? If you add an else statement with a print (for all of the lines that don't match), are some of the rows you expect to match printing?

Comment: Just in case I'd add the raw text `r` in front of your drive names in lines 3/4 (workdir and dst).  e.g.  `dst = os.path.join(r'T:\gis','Images2017','jp2','1foot')`

Comment: Note: I think I saw that searchCursor is deprecated, you should switch to arcpy.da.SearchCursor (in the Data Access module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I would take. This assumes the field "rasters" has row values without the ".jp2" extension.

```
import arcpy, os, shutil

fc = r'X:\temp\myfc.shp' # The input featureclass or shapefile
inws = r'X:\temp' # The input workspace with JP2 files
outws = r'X:\temp\out_jp2' # The destination workspace to copy JP2 files

# Loop through all the rows in the "rasters" field
for jp2 in [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "rasters")]:
    jp2_path = os.path.join(inws, jp2 + ".jp2") # Make a full file path to the file
    if os.path.isfile(jp2_path): # Some logic to make sure the file is actually a file
        shutil.copyfile(jp2_path, os.path.join(outws, jp2 + ".jp2")) # Copy the file

print "Processing complete."
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Aaron! I ran the code and received the Processing complete message, but unfortunately the files weren't copied. I am trying to understand first line of the loop. What does `row[0] for row` means?

Comment: Could you please add the results of `print(jp2_path)`?

Comment: Ok so it worked. The issue was that the values in the FC field had a different initial than the files, so I had to change these using Field Calculator. Thank you!